# Getting the value of next time (from the list) based on the incoming value of time

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have predefined shifts of time `00:00:00, 06:00:00, 14:00:00, 22:00:00`. If the incoming `time_id`  is let's say between `00:00:00 and 06:00:00` then I want to assign the `start_shift_time` a value of `06:00:00`. If it is between `06:00:00 and 14:00:00` then assign `start_shift_time` a value of `14:00:00`.
I have already written this block but I am not sure what will be from for this select. The block is a part of a big stored procedure/function.

```
SELECT
    start_shift_time,
    CASE WHEN CAST(rt_time_id as time) >= '00:00:00' or CAST(rt_time_id as time) < '06:00:00' 
        THEN start_shift_time = '06:00:00' 
    WHEN CAST(rt_time_id as time) >= '06:00:00' or CAST(rt_time_id as time) < '14:00:00' 
        THEN start_shift_time = '14:00:00' 
    WHEN CAST(rt_time_id as time) >= '14:00:00' or CAST(rt_time_id as time) < '00:00:00' 
        THEN start_shift_time = '00:00:00'
```

Comment: show us your sample data and your desired output

Answer (score 0):

Time column can never be less that 00:00:00 so your 3rd condition can never be true. Now you could just drop the second predicate. But you would still have to correct the [CASE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) syntax. That syntax is

```
case when condition1 then result
     when condition2 then result 
     ...
     else result  
 end result_name ; 

It is not as you have:

case when condition1 then result_name = result
     when condition2 then result_name = result
     ...;
```

The other nice thing about it is when a condition evaluates True the result is set/calculated and statement/expression processing terminates immediately. So here you can eliminate "or time < 00:00:00". But you can greatly simply by reversing the order checked and elminating all the "OR" (which should be "AND"). So:

```
select case when cast(rt_time_id as time) >= '14:00:00'::time then '00:00:00'::time
            when cast(rt_time_id as time) >= '06:00:00'::time then '14:00:00'::time         
            else '06:00:00'::time
       end as start_shift_time   
 from shifts ;
```

Note: Your description also mentions time 22:00:00 but your query does not. The above follows the query.